# How to prevent my Selenium/Python program from crashing?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, scrapy

I made a program which gets one record from Google Sheet process on it then delete it and so on. If I update Google Sheet then the program will deduct record in the next loop and process on it and then delete, 
but it runs only 1 or 2 hours and then program gives an error:

[image]

What can I add in my program so my program never stops?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import traceback
import string
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException


Email=raw_input('Please Enter your Email:  ')
password=raw_input('Please Enter Password:  ')


print("\n******Don't Interrupt the Script******")
print('#script is Runing............\n')



chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #going to chrome options
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2 #turn off all notifications
         ,"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2} #disable images 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) # passing paramaters to chrome

driver.get('https://accounts.google.com')
time.sleep(3)

#giving Email-------------------
email = driver.find_element_by_id('Email')
email.send_keys(Email, Keys.RETURN)

#giving password----------------
time.sleep(3)
email = driver.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
email.send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)


#credentials + attach with googleSheet------------------------------ 
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('stephens-31d8490b5bd2.json', scope)
google_sheet = gspread.authorize(credentials)
workSheet = google_sheet.open("Video Access Master Sheet").worksheet("Sheet1")



while True:
    #fetch Records from Rows 2 to 50 and save on list-----------------
    for i in range(2,51): 
        li_url=[]
        li_email=[]
        row=workSheet.row_values(i)
        for b in row:
            if 'youtu' in b:
                li_url.append(b)

                #find record which you append on list and then delete from googleSheet--------------------
                cell = workSheet.find(b)
                row = cell.row
                col = cell.col
                workSheet.update_cell(row,col, '')
                print 'Fetching Values From Row '+str(i)+'....'
            elif '@' in b:
                li_email.append(b)
            elif b=='':
                continue
            else:
                continue

        #*********************************************************
        #getting length list of li_url and apply condition on it-----------------------------------------------
        length=len(li_url)
        if length==0:
            continue
        else:
            try:
                #getting URLs from list and put into driver.get---------------------------------------------------------
                for a in li_url:
                    driver.get(a)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-uix-button-icon.yt-uix-button-icon-info.yt-sprite').click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-uix-button.yt-uix-button-size-default.yt-uix-button-default.metadata-share-button').click()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    put_email=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-uix-form-input-textarea.metadata-share-contacts')

                    #getting emails from email list--------------------------------------------------------------
                    put_email.send_keys(li_email[0])
                    time.sleep(2)
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-uix-button.yt-uix-button-size-default.yt-uix-button-primary.sharing-dialog-button.sharing-dialog-ok').click()
                    time.sleep(4)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-header"]/div/button[2]/span').click()
                    time.sleep(10)

                #for notifications and alters--------------------------------------------   
                try:
                    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
                except NoAlertPresentException:
                    pass
                except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
                    pass
            except:
                traceback.print_exc
                pass

        print 'Row '+str(i)+' Successfully Updated. \n'
    time.sleep(120) #while loop sleep for 20minuts
```

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 56, in parse
  File "<string>", line 35, in parse
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: I think It shows error if there is no record any more . So what i think is you need to check the empty record. If there is no record then stop. some kind of things

Comment: I agree. The error has something to do with how you check for rows. Why don't you try `if row_values(i) is None: continue`

Comment: loop will run every every 2min and check all rows..

Comment: @Sai  elif b=='': continue, i'm already use

Comment: @RashidAziz Can you post a exception raised as a text in the question? It will be more readable that your photo.

Comment: Yep please to posting text as text. The Windows terminal has a clipboard feature.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski something like that..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 56, in parse
  File "<string>", line 35, in parse
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: @halfer 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 56, in parse
  File "<string>", line 35, in parse
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: ^ Please add _into_ your question as a formatted block, thanks.

Comment: I think the error happens here `row=workSheet.row_values(i)`. Make sure that the row contains values before you even retrieve it.

Comment: @halfer added into formatted block.. kindly check it

Comment: Your new code block doesn't seem to have the same contents as your screenshot. Please re-run the error and paste the error exactly, and then remove the screenshot.

Comment: You should take a screenshot of the error instead of taking a photo. On Windows, you can take a screenshot by pressing the Print Screen keyboard button and then pasting into Paint.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `cell = workSheet.find(b)` fails. Could be bad data in there; without seeing the input it's anyone's guess.

Since you already know the row number, you can avoid using `cell = workSheet.find(b)` by simply keeping track of the columns you're searching through and finally calling `workSheet.update_cell(i, col, '')` after copying the data.

Comment: i don't think so.. because my programs works perfectly almost 1 hour, but after this it give raise error.. 
i think something wrong with loop.. which is not continually work.. but i don't know how i can resolve it.. :(